# Profile with only one object permission

Tags: profile, permission-sets

I need to create a profile which has only read access for only one custom object.
I dont want to provide any other object access for this profile.
The problem i am facing is that while creating a new profile, it asks to base the new profile on an existing profile. Existing profiles have access to many objects which i need to remove manually.
Which profile should i select while creating new profile so that i can quickly create a new profile with only required access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the Salesforce standard 'Read Only' profile.  You will then need to edit your new profile and remove access to all objects other than your custom object.